# Массив чисел в одно число через Stream

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-8, java-stream

Дано - входящий массив; из которого нужно убрать все дубликаты и вернуть число, состоящее из оставшихся чисел массива. Реализовать нужно через Stream.
Пример - вошел массив `{1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3}` - вернулось число `123`.

Текущая реализация:

```
private static int minValue(int[] array) {
    int[] noDuplicates = IntStream.of(array).distinct().toArray();
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = noDuplicates.length - 1, n = 0; i >= 0; --i, n++) {
        int pos = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
        result += noDuplicates[n] * pos;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Но нужно реализовать через один лишь Stream, без использования циклов.
Точнее, используя терминальные операции, которые сводят stream чисел в одно число по заданному алгоритму. Прошу подсказать, как это реализовать

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так?

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3).stream().distinct().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()); // вернёт 123
```

Если результат нужен именно как `int`:

```
int res = Integer.valueOf(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3).stream().distinct().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Если без строк, то можно как-то так:

```
int res = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3)
    .stream()
    .distinct()
    .reduce(0, (a,b) -> (a + b * (int)(a == 0 ? 1 :Math.pow(10, (int) (Math.log10(a) + 1)))));
```

Только на выходе будет `321`. Остаётся только перевернуть.

Comment: Забыл добавить; что при всём при этом нельзя использовать преобразование в String и обратно. Таково задание...

Comment: Всё намного проще, чем степени и логарифмы)

Answer (score 2):

```java
int result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3)
        .distinct()
        .reduce(0, (a,b) -> 10 * a + b);
```

Результат: `123`.

---

Но это только для чисел меньших 10-ти, для чисел больших 10-ти немного сложнее:

```java
int result = Stream.of(1, 123, 2, 3, 22, 2, 2, 3, 22, 10)
        .distinct()
        .reduce(0, (a,b) -> (int)Math.pow(10, (int)(Math.log10(b) + 1)) * a + b);
```

Результат: `1123232210`.

Comment: Реверса кажется не хватает

Comment: @tym32167 всё правильно.

Comment: В час ночи голова у меня совсем не варила :D